# Cast void* to std::map

Tags: c++, pointers, void-pointers, stdmap

I'm trying to store a std::map on a shared memory segment. But I'm not being able to recover the map.

I create the shared memory segment (using the class below) and assign the map address to it.

But when I try to recover it I get a bad pointer.

Here are some code snippets:

```
    // This is in my header file
    CSharedMem * shMem;
    // This is in my cpp file - inside my class constructor
    shMem = new CSharedMem("MyShMem", 16536);
    void * ptr = shMem->GetAddress();
    std::map<int,int> myMap;
    ptr = &myMap;
    shMem-ReleaseAddress();

    // This is inside another function
    void * ptr = shMem->GetAdress();

    std::map<int,int> myMap = *static_cast<std::map<int,int> *> (ptr);
```

Does anyone have a clue?

CSharedMem class
Header file:

```
    #pragma once

    #include <string>

    class CSharedMem
    {
    public:
    CSharedMem(const std::string& name, std::size_t size);
    ~CSharedMem();

    void* GetAddress() const;
    void ReleaseAddress();
    bool IsShared() const;
    private:
    bool shared_;
    void* address_;

    private:
    void* shm_;
    void* mtx_;
    };
```

cpp file:

```
    #include "StdAfx.h"
    #include "SharedMem.h"
    #include <windows.h>
    CSharedMem::CSharedMem(const std::string& name, std::size_t size)
    : shared_(false), 
    address_(NULL)
    {
    shm_ = CreateFileMapping(INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, 
                            NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 
                            0, 
                            static_cast<DWORD>(size), 
                            name.c_str() );
    if( shm_ == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
            throw std::exception("Failed to allocate shared memory.");

    if( GetLastError() == ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS )
            shared_ = true;

    address_ = MapViewOfFile(shm_, FILE_MAP_READ | FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
    if( address_ == NULL )
            throw std::exception("Failed to map shared memory.");

    if( !shared_ )
            std::memset(address_, 0, size);

    mtx_ = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, (name + "MTX").c_str());
    if( mtx_ == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
            throw std::exception("Failed to create shared mutex.");
    }

    CSharedMem::~CSharedMem()
    {
    UnmapViewOfFile(address_);
    CloseHandle(mtx_);
    }
    void* CSharedMem::GetAddress() const
    {
    if(WaitForSingleObject(mtx_, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0)
            throw std::exception("Failed to obtain access to shared memory.");

    return address_;
    }

    void CSharedMem::ReleaseAddress()
    {
            ReleaseMutex(mtx_);
    }

    bool CSharedMem::IsShared() const
    {
            return shared_;
    }
```

Comment: Your code cannot possibly work. The problem is more complicated than it seems. Read up on STL allocators and placement new. You need both concepts. Also you have to allocate your shared memory segment at a fixed address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something is fishy with this logic:

```
void * ptr = shMem->GetAddress();
std::map<int,int> myMap;
ptr = &myMap;
shMem->ReleaseAddress();
```

Notice that you obtain an address with `shMem->GetAddress()`, but then declare a local variable `myMap` and then assign `ptr` the address of the local variable.  This means that you won't actually have `ptr` pointing at that shared memory any more.

I'm not sure what the fix to this is, since I'm not sure I see what you're trying to do here.  If you intended to cast the shared memory you got to be a pointer to a map, perhaps you meant this:

```
void * ptr = shMem->GetAddress();

/* Construct a map at the given address using placement new. */
new (ptr) std::map<int, int>();
shMem-ReleaseAddress();
```

Later on, you can retrieve the map:

```
void* ptr = shMem->GetAdress();

/* Note the use of a reference here so we don't just make a copy. */
std::map<int,int> myMap& = *static_cast<std::map<int,int> *> (ptr);
```

That said, I'm extremely doubtful that this will work because the pointers allocated internally inside the `map` will be local to the process that creates them, not shared.  You'd probably need to do something fancy with allocators to get this to work correctly.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think you're right. I'll be able to test it early in the morning when I got to work (9 hours from here). Thanks for the tip! I'll reply again when I get to test it.

Comment: @templatetypedef +1 for noting the & for not making a copy. Great answer

Answer (score 4):

Following on a comment above, this is not as simple as it sounds.  If you are using shared memory across processes, you cannot pass STL containers.

However, you can use the containers in the [`boost::interprocess`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/allocators_containers.html) library.  This library specifically provides containers (vector, deque, set, map) that can be used within a shared memory segment, and the documentation provides lots of examples.